# Using JPA NamedQuery to obtain result list

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I want to get a list of results using the query as below:

```
SELECT x FROM XTreinamentosOrc x WHERE x.codEduca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso y FROM XRlz y WHERE y.matricula = :matricula)
```

I have used it in its entity class, but then I've got the Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb_treinamentos.entities.XTreinamentosOrc' does not have the property 'matricula'.
```

The matricula field is obtained when the user successfully logs in the app.
It should be setted in the NamedQuery via CDI to query the database.
The matricula field is located in another table different from the one mapped here.

How can I set the injected sessionChave String in parameter matricula, which is of XRlzConsolidado class type?

The bean:

```
@Named(value = "ExtratoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ExtratoBean implements Serializable {

@EJB
private XTreinamentosOrcFacade xt;

@Inject
@SessionChave
private String sessionChave;

private List<XTreinamentosOrc> xTreinamentosOrcList;

public List<XTreinamentosOrc> getxTreinamentosOrcList() {
    return QueryExtratoTreinamentos();
}

private List QueryExtratoTreinamentos() {
    List<XTreinamentosOrc> extratoTreinamentosOrcList = null;
    XRlzConsolidado x = new XRlzConsolidado();
    x.setMatricula(sessionChave);
    extratoTreinamentosOrcList = xt.findAllTreinamentosByMatricula(x);
    return extratoTreinamentosOrcList;
}
}
```

There are 3 entities: XRlz, XRlzConsolidado and XTreinamentosOrc.

The XRlz:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XRlz", catalog = "diage", schema = "atb")
@XmlRootElement
//named queries

public class XRlz implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;
@Column(name = "uorPos")
private Integer uorPos;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "nomeUorPos")
private String nomeUorPos;
@Column(name = "codCurso")
private Integer codCurso;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "nomeCurso")
private String nomeCurso;
@Column(name = "qtdCursos2015")
private Integer qtdCursos2015;
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "dtConclusao")
private String dtConclusao;
@JoinColumn(name = "matricula", referencedColumnName = "matricula")
@ManyToOne
private XRlzConsolidado matricula;
@JoinColumn(name = "dtRef", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private XDatas dtRef;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS

public XRlzConsolidado getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(XRlzConsolidado matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public XDatas getDtRef() {
    return dtRef;
}

public void setDtRef(XDatas dtRef) {
    this.dtRef = dtRef;
}

//equals/hashcode/toString 

}
```

The XRlzConsolidado:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XRlzConsolidado", catalog = "diage", schema = "atb")
@XmlRootElement
// NamedQueries

public class XRlzConsolidado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "matricula")
    private String matricula;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "uorPos")
    private Integer uorPos;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "nomeuorPos")
    private String nomeuorPos;
    @Column(name = "capacitacaoGestores")
    private Integer capacitacaoGestores;
    @Column(name = "capacitacaoAssessores")
    private Integer capacitacaoAssessores;
    @Column(name = "horas")
    private Integer horas;
    @Column(name = "bemEstar")
    private Integer bemEstar;
    @Column(name = "inovEfic")
    private Integer inovEfic;
    @Column(name = "qtdCursos2015")
    private Integer qtdCursos2015;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "matricula")
    private Collection<XRlz> xRlzCollection;

    public XRlzConsolidado() {
    }

    public XRlzConsolidado(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

// getters and setters

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<XRlz> getXRlzCollection() {
        return xRlzCollection;
    }

    public void setXRlzCollection(Collection<XRlz> xRlzCollection) {
        this.xRlzCollection = xRlzCollection;
    }

    // hashCode()

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof XRlzConsolidado)) {
            return false;
        }
        XRlzConsolidado other = (XRlzConsolidado) object;
        if ((this.matricula == null && other.matricula != null) || (this.matricula != null && !this.matricula.equals(other.matricula))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // toString
}
```

The XTreinamentosOrc:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XTreinamentosOrc", catalog = "diage", schema = "atb")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "XTreinamentosOrc.findAll", query = "SELECT x FROM XTreinamentosOrc x"),
@NamedQuery(name = "XTreinamentosOrc.findAllTreinamentosByMatricula", query = "SELECT x FROM XTreinamentosOrc x WHERE x.codEduca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso FROM XRlz y WHERE y.matricula = :matricula)")})

public class XTreinamentosOrc implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "codEduca")
    private int codEduca;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "nomeCurso")
    private String nomeCurso;
    @Column(name = "cargaHoraria")
    private Integer cargaHoraria;
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private XTipo tipo;
    @JoinColumn(name = "segmento", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private XSegmento segmento;
    @JoinColumn(name = "modalidade", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private XModalidade modalidade;
    @JoinColumn(name = "dtRef", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private XDatas dtRef;

    public XTreinamentosOrc() {
    }

    public XTreinamentosOrc(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public XTreinamentosOrc(Integer id, int codEduca) {
        this.id = id;
        this.codEduca = codEduca;
    }

    // hashCode() {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof XTreinamentosOrc)) {
            return false;
        }
        XTreinamentosOrc other = (XTreinamentosOrc) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso y` (note the `y` that was removed)

Comment: Ok, but no success, the Exception remains the same. Any other hint?

Comment: The hint is the exception message. Have you read it? It says exactly what the problem is: the field XRlz.matricula is of type XRlzConsolidado, and you're trying to compare it with a String. The code you posted is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Yes, I read it, and I don't know how to resolve it. I've posted a more relevant code. How can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: resolve it ? you compare a String with a String, or a XRlzConsolidado with a XRlzConsolidado

Comment: @Neil Stockton, ok, but I'm confused to do it in the query (see the updated question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you post code for `XRlzConsolidado`? It probably contains a string field you want to compare with `sessionChave`. You are comparing field XRlz.matricula with string value, but it is of type `XRlzConsolidado`

Comment: I've posted it, see above. Thanks.

Comment: That's right, I just adjusted the query to compare elements of the same type:  `SELECT x FROM XTreinamentosOrc x WHERE x.codEduca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso FROM XRlz y WHERE y.matricula.matricula = :matricula)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the name of your query.  findAllTreinamentosByMatricula() is a Property Expression and can refer only to a direct property of the managed entity.  findAllTreinamentosByMatricula will look in the XTreinamentosOrc class for the property called matricula.  When that property is not found in XTreinamentosOrc you get the exception:

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb_treinamentos.entities.XTreinamentosOrc' does not have the property 'matricula'.

You need to change the name of your query to something like:

> @NamedQuery(name = "XTreinamentosOrc.find", query = "SELECT x FROM XTreinamentosOrc x WHERE x.codEduca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT y.codCurso FROM XRlz y WHERE y.matricula = :matricula)")})

(I may be off with the method name 'find() so you may need to do some more research' for acceptable format)

check out this documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions